# I want to put a button next to a Dropdown list in asp.net

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

This is probably a very basic question, but I want to put a button next to a dropdown list.

I would like to do it **without altering the CSS**. I've been trying for a long time and cannot manage to get it right, I know there's a simple way to do it but I'm stumped

**code:**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="Grupo">TI's</label>
       <select class="form-control" id="TIDropDown"></select>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></span>
       </button>
   </div>
</div>
```

and this is what it displays:

[image]

I would like for the button to appear next to it, as to add more dropdowns dynamically.

Thanks.

Comment: You should edit your tags. This is an html question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/)

You could use [Input Group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/input-group/) like this...

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="input-group">
     <select class="custom-select" id="TIDropDown">
       <option>Choose...</option>
       <option>Option 1</option>
       <option>Option 2</option>
     </select>

     <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></span>
        </button>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class "row" to your group.
Then you can divide the spaces.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="Grupo">TI's</label>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <select class="form-control" id="TIDropDown"></select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default ">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```